# Fastest way to clean HTML from String and return results in Array Android / Java

Tags: java, android, arrays, regex, replace

I was using JSOUP parsing a html string within a for loop containing 900 entries, however, the async task takes around 40 seconds to complete (unacceptable) when trying to read out sections of the html... string.replace() takes it down to 8 to 10 seconds.

JSOUP like so is pretty fast:

```
element.text();
```

JSOUP like so is slow:

```
element.html();
```

I can use the JSOUP text() on everything but the 2nd href, which I need a number out of (948 in the string below). So I need to use the .html() and then .replace on...

I have a string that looks like this (same structure, different data each time):

```
String siteDescription = "<b><font size='+2'>46Q01S: Mt. Ryan</font></b><hr></hr><table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' width='400'>" +
                "<tr><td>Elev: 2800 feet</td></tr><tr><td>Snow Water Equivalent: 2.4 inches</td><td>Snow Water Equivalent: 92 pct norm</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Water Year Precipitation: 2 inches</td><td>Water Year Precipitation: 66 pct norm</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td>Snow Depth: 14 inches</td><td>Snow Density: 17 percent</td></tr>" +
                "<tr><td><a href='http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/cgibin/wygraph-multi.pl?state=AK&amp;wateryear=current&amp;stationidname=46Q01S'>Time Series Chart</a></td>" +
                "<td><a href='http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/nwcc/site?sitenum=948'>Site Info</a></td></tr></table>" +
                "<a href='http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/siteimages/948.jpg'><img width='400' alt='img not available' src='http://www.wcc.nrcs.usda.gov/siteimages/948.jpg'/></a><hr></hr>" +
                "Generated: 26 Dec 2014";
```

I am trying to refine my code and also figure out if I really need to do as much .replace() as I am doing with regex somehow? In the end I am adding it to an Array to easily use the pieces out of this description. I am adding a comma after each `</td>` and the 2 `<hr><hr>` tags to easily read it out of the string array. Here is my replacing:

```
String descrip = siteDescription.replace(
    "<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"400\">", "");
String descri = descrip.replace("<td>", "");
String descr = descri.replace("</td>", ",");
String desc = descr.replace("</table>", "");
String des = desc.replace("<tr>", "");
String de = des.replace("</tr>", "");
String d = de.replace("<hr></hr>", ",");

String Name;
String Elevation;
String SWEinches;
String SWEPercentNormal;
String WYPinches;
String WYPPercentNormal;
String SnowDepth;
String SnowDensity;
String SiteImage;
String siteNumber;

String[] splitData = d.split(",");
for (int j = 0; j < splitData.length; j++) {
    splitData[j].replaceAll("\\W", "");
}
if (splitData[0] != null) {
    Name = splitData[0];
} else {
    Name = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[1] != null) {
    Elevation = splitData[1];
} else {
    Elevation = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[2] != null) {
    SWEinches = splitData[2];
} else {
    SWEinches = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[3] != null) {
    SWEPercentNormal = splitData[3];
} else {
    SWEPercentNormal = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[4] != null) {
    WYPinches = splitData[4];
} else {
    WYPinches = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[5] != null) {
    WYPPercentNormal = splitData[5];
} else {
    WYPPercentNormal = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[6] != null) {
    SnowDepth = splitData[6];
} else {
    SnowDepth = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[7] != null) {
    SnowDensity = splitData[7];
} else {
    SnowDensity = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[8] != null) {
    SiteImage = splitData[8];
} else {
    SiteImage = "N/A";
}
if (splitData[9] != null) {
    siteNumber = splitData[9].replaceAll("\\D", "");
} else {
    siteNumber = "000000";
}
```

The data I need is in the table (between the `<td>`). Is there an easier way to do this? Faster way? Better way?! I have created a [quick Runnable that will hopefully helpout](http://runnable.com/VKoNEDhQ3U1l8aJ6/stringreplace-kml-snotel-data-for-java).

EDIT:::: I had a thought after submitting this that using JSOUP and selecting the single image element like so would be quicker:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(siteDescription);
//THIS WORKS FAST ENOUGH...
                    Elements tds = doc.getElementsByTag("td");
                    for (int i = 0; i < tds.size(); i++) {
                        //Log.e("TD", i + " : " + tds.get(5).text());
                        siteSnowDepth = tds.get(5).text();
                    }
//THIS ACTUALLY DOES TOO!
                    Elements imgs = doc.select("img");
                    for (int i = 0; i < imgs.size(); i++) {
                        Log.v("LINK", imgs.attr("src").replaceAll("\\D", ""));
                    }
```

Comment: Try reducing your replace calls using a regex e.g. desc.replace("</?tr>", ""); to match both the tr open and close tags at once.

Comment: String descrip = siteDescription.replaceAll("</td>|<hr></hr>", ",");
String d = descrip.replaceAll(
    "</?t([dr]|able)>|<table cellspacing=\"0\" cellpadding=\"0\" width=\"400\">", "");